# Can't get a variable to be displayed on Angular HTML template

Tags: angular, typescript

I know this is a simple problem, but for some reason I can't get a piece of data to display in my Angular 6 HTML template.

Shouldn't all the data be added to checkTime? I tried making checkTime an array as the data might be coming in an array format with length equal to 1. When taking that approach, I did the whole ***ngFor** as well, but it didn't work.

Here is how the data comes from the API I'm calling in my service:

```
[
    {
        "CheckTimes": 1
    }
]
```

Here is all of my code:

**HTML Template:**

```
<p>{{ checkTime.result }}</p>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { VerificationService, Verification } from '../verification.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-verification',
  templateUrl: './verification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./verification.component.css']
})
export class VerificationComponent implements OnInit {

  checkTime: Verification;

  constructor(
    public verificationService: VerificationService
  ) { 
    this.getTimeVerification();
  }

  getTimeVerification(){
    this.verificationService.getTimeVerification().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.checkTime = data
        console.log(data)
      },
      error => {
        alert("Could not retrieve time verification")
      }
    )
  }
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface Verification {
  result: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VerificationService {

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getTimeVerification(){
    let url = this.baseUrl + '/api/verify_times';
    return this.http.get<Verification>(url);
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you seeing the data in the console?

Comment: This makes no sense. Your code says that the data is of type Verification, so some kind of object I presume (you haven't posted its definition). But your JSON says you're getting an array, which has a single object, which has a single field named CheckTimes. And your template is not iterating over any array, and is trying to show a field named "result", which clearly doesn't exist in the JSON.

Comment: So, check what you're actually receiving, and fix the backend or the frontend code.

Comment: @AndreiDumitrescu-Tudor I'm seeing the data in the console.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried doing checkTime: Verification[]; as an array, and then did interating in the template, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Try my suggestion below.

Comment: Again, the unique object in the array has a single property named "CheckTimes". None named "result".

Comment: @AndrWeisR that solution did not work.

Comment: Try making checkTime:any and if that works the problem is with your model.

Comment: @JBNizet in the service where I call the API I map it to an interface, which has result in it. Is that incorrect?

Comment: If you receive a banana from the server, telling to TypeScript "trust me, what I receive is a Car" won't turn the banana into a Car. Fields won't magically appear in the JSON that you actually received from the server.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay so I made checkTime type any, and then in the html template I did {{ checkTime }}. Now it says [object Object], which makes sense, but I don't know how to access a specific attribute of that object.

Comment: Don't use `any`. Use a type that actually matches with what the server sends. It sends an `Array<{ CheckTimes: number; }>`. If you want the value of this CheckTimes property, you need `{{ checkTime[0].CheckTimes }}`.

Comment: @JBNizet That did the trick, thank you. I didn't realize how precise I had to be.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest don't call getTimeVerification in your constructor, but rather in ngOnInit. The constructor is too soon.

Comment: It's not a solution at all.

Comment: You think it, maybe, but what you're thinking is wrong. It's indeed a better practice to use injected services in ngOnInit, but it's not icorrect to use them in the constructor, and using ngOnInit won't change anything to the actual problem that the OP has.